# trying to get json data from api .... I'm on localhost

Tags: json, ajax, api

I am trying to get json data from http://gulf-shade.com/test/asd.php and it always says  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
here is my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://gulf-shade.com/test/asd.php", true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4 || xhr.status != 200) return;
    result = xhr.response.data;
         cosnole.log(result);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the site your are trying to access has CORS enabled which disallow any requests coming from JavaScript from another domain, in your case (localhost).

You can't make Ajax request to this service unless it allowed localhsot as an origin and if you can't do that, then at least you can create your localhost API which calls the `http://gulf-shade.com/test/asd.php` URL, retrieves the data and return it to your Ajax request.